# Google Apps Script Success Handler Running before function is fully executed

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have a dialog I'm displaying via the html service in Google Apps Script. From the dialog, I call a google script function (`openFormSidebar`) that opens a sidebar with a success handler to close the dialog.

**HTML in Dialog**

```
<button
onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close()).openFormSidebar()">
Create Form</button>
```

The problem is that the dialog is closing (the success handler is running) before the sidebar is opened.

**gs code**

```
function openFormSidebar () {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('FormSidebar')
         .setTitle('Form Creation')
         .setWidth(300)
         .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
     SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
     .showSidebar(html);
}
```

Even if I make the `openFormSidebar` function a simple logger statement (i.e. `Logger.log('test')`) it doesn't execute (nothing is logged).

What am I missing? Why is this occuring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close()).openFormSidebar()` **calls** `google.script.host.close()` and then passes its return value into `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler`, exactly the way `foo(bar());` **calls** `bar` and then passes its return value in to `foo`.

You'll want to pass in a function reference instead:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function() { google.script.host.close() }).openFormSidebar()`
```

or possibly

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close.bind(google.script.host)).openFormSidebar()`
```

`Function#bind` returns a function that, when called, calls the original with a given `this` value. So `google.script.host.close.bind(google.script.host)` creates a function that, when called, will call `google.script.host.close` with `this` set to `google.script.host`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually just removing the () after close should work the way you expect.